# Different behavior of set-car! on two lists which look the same

Tags: scheme

I'm confused about the result of the application of `set-car!` to two lists which have the same structure, but were constructed differently.

So here is a code example for the two lists `m` and `n`:

```
(define m
  (cons
    (cons 'a '())
    (cons
      (cons 'a '())
      '())))
(display m)(newline) ; => ((a) (a))
(set-car! (cadr m) 'b)
(display m)(newline) ; => ((a) (b))

(newline)

(define n (list '(x) '(x)))
(display n)(newline) ; => ((x) (x))
(set-car! (cadr n) 'y)
(display n)(newline) ; => ((y) (y))
```

According do `display`, both lists have the same structure, but why does applying the same procedure on them result in different behavior? Does it have to do with the way they were constructed?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The results *should* be the same for both lists. What Scheme interpreter are you using? it seems to me that your interpreter reuses the `'(x)` expression.

After the comments, it seems that in fact this is a bug in the interpreter. Both lists should behave the same after the modifications.

Comment: Most implementations I know of _do_ reuse literal datums. They are allowed to, because it's invalid to modify literals; that's "nasal demon territory".

Comment: He might have been using IronScheme ;p http://eval.ironscheme.net/?id=68 Edit: Which may imply some bug with mutating constants... :*(

Comment: I've tested the code on different scheme implementations: IronScheme (thanks leppie), mit-scheme and guile 1.8. They all show the same behavior for both list constructs, only guile 2.0.5 differs. So I think it's a bug in guile 2.0.5.

Comment: @MarcP. Wrong. It's not a bug. You're not allowed to mutate literals. ([R5RS](http://www.schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/r5rs-Z-H-6.html#%_sec_3.4), [R6RS](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs/r6rs-Z-H-8.html#node_sec_5.10)) R6RS does say that implementations "should" (not "must") signal an exception in that case, and perhaps more implementations "should", but in such a scenario, any kind of behaviour in appropriate, and you should have no expectations of anything in specific.

Comment: @MarcP. The difference you see in Guile 2.0 is that Guile ([from 2.0.2 onwards](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=guile.git;a=blob;f=NEWS;h=64d374d9dc8aee45113dc25f517dce5335ff3beb;hb=1321a36ed61deb9431b41768dc92cb7230c9afa1#l565)) has an optimisation called constant folding, so the same list constant `'(x)` can be folded into the same object. So, if you **erroneously** modify one, this will be observable in other places that use the same object. But this behaviour is allowed.

Comment: @leppie It's certainly better (from R6RS's point of view) to diagnose mutations of constants, but it's certainly not required, and IronScheme is not non-compliant for failing to diagnose it.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young: I think I may have misread my results earlier ;p The last one is `((x) (y))` indeed and not what I thought I saw.